# Updating acl file using JS in hyperledger-composer

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am working on hyperledger playground. I have found that the access rules for participants can be specified manually on acl file in hyperledger composer. But is there a way that allows me to add rules to this file using JS?

**Example:**

There is an organization. It has some assets, and its number of employees is not fixed. As the admin adds new employees, their access rights on these assets is not known beforehand. 
Is there a way such that as new employees are added, I can dynamically create rules for them, modifying the .acl file by script?

Answer (score 0):

see the condition property in the reference doc https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/acl_language. As the condition property accepts code, you can invoke functions that exist within your business network .js files, however these functions are not allowed to invoke the composer runtime API. A summary of those functions not allowed can be found here
https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/api/runtime-api

If you try to use them it will throw an error.